# What is the purpose of the service account referenced by a Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm struggling to understand what the purpose it serves?

For example in the following pod definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
```

When does the service account "matter"? In what interactions is it involved in?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/ explains how to set a non default one, but doesn't really mention what effect / interactions are changed - or why you would need to do this?

The only hint it really gives is this section:

> Processes in containers inside pods can also contact the apiserver.
>   When they do, they are authenticated as a particular Service Account
>   (for example, default).

Which makes no sense what so ever. How does a arbitrary process magically become "authenticated" when it sends an HTTP request to the kubernetes API server?

Are there security benefits? If so what are they?

Answer (score 2):

Pod which need to interact with Kubernetes API Server needs a service account to authenticate to Kubernetes API Server.

To communicate with the API server, a Pod uses a ServiceAccount containing an authentication token. Roles (e.g: the right to list all the Pods within a given namespace), or ClusterRole (eg: the right to read all the Secrets within the entire cluster), can then be bound to this ServiceAccount. Respectively with a RoleBinding or a ClusterRoleBinding, so the ServiceAccount is authorized to perform those actions.

A lot of applications that run in the cluster (read: running in Pods), need to communicate with the API server. Among them are the processes running within the Control Plane (scheduler, controller manager, proxy, etc.), as well as all the applications that need to perform some form of administration for the cluster such as controllers which manages custom resources.

Comment: What is defined as a "pod" here though? Is this related to the kubelet functionality RELATED to the pod? Otherwise a pod is just a arbitrary container - why would it have any direct interaction with the Kubernetes API?

Comment: for example a controller or operator running as pod which manages custom resource needs to interact with k8s API to watch on the custom resource

Comment: How does the controller / container magically get authenticated though? It'll send an API request to `https://192.168.39.143:8443`  for example. How does that request magically get the authentication token / certificate attached to it?

Comment: well there are different ways to authenticate with k8s API...certificate is one bearer token is another way..service accounts have a secret attached which has a JWT  bearer token

Comment: Exactly. So the request is intercepted / proxied and a valid authentication "something" is attached onto it? This sounds completely crazy.

Comment: there is no request interception...the code written using client library inside the pod needs to read the token from the secret and call k8s API using that token as bearer token

Comment: Then why wouldn't we just use a secret rather than a whole new  definition + a huge page about this in documentation?

Comment: service accounts internally uses secret to store the token...the advantage of using service account is that it will always have a short lived and valid token

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the ServiceAccount is required when you have RBAC active in your cluster (you should!) and your Pod has to communicate with the Kubernetes API.

Let's assume you have a pod that uses the Kubernetes Client to extend the kubernetes behavior. For example, you can send a message on Slack every time a Kubernetes Node joins the cluster. In order to allow the program running in your Pod to interact with the Kubernetes API, you have to pass a certificate. The ServiceAccount does that for you. And based on the ServiceAccount you use you can limit permissions.

Almost like in the AWS world an EC2 gets authentication to the AWS API via IAM Role and EC2 Profile.

Comment: "you have to pass a certificate". Yup makes sense though, how does the service account "interaction" intercept/modify this request?

Answer (score 0):

`api-server` understands two types of requests: authenticated and unauthenticated. Then, the authenticated requests can be authorized or not authorized.

A `Service Account`, a `User` or a `Group` (group of users) are objects containing certain permissions to interact with `api-server`.

You would use `User` or `Group` to give access to one individual or a group of people, to interact with `api-server`; mostly through `kubectl`. You can also `curl` the `api-server` endpoint though, as RESTful API, with the certificates.

But when you need a micro service (a pod) to interact with `api-server`, you need to specify a `Service Account`; also with all the necessary permissions.

All the permissions are given through RBAC rules.

**Conclusion:**
You would create a `User` or `Group` and give it certain permissions to interact with `api-server` as person.

You would create a `Service Account`, and give it certain permissions, if you'd want the pod to interact with `api-server` as server (not as person).

Comment: This does not answer what the interaction is between the pod and service account. Everyone has identified it's involved in authentication - but no explanation is given how this is meant to work.

Comment: When you create a service account, it automatically creates a secret with the certs to identify this service account. On top of that you give some permissions to that service account and voilà.

Answer (score 0):

It relates to the https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/

The fact that the documentation makes no mention of this is really surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet from

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/kubernetes-service-accounts

Kubernetes service accounts let you give an identity to your Pods, which can be used to

1. Authenticate Pods to the Kubernetes API server, allowing the Pods to read and manipulate Kubernetes API objects (for example, a CI/CD pipeline that deploys applications to your cluster).
   Example: FluxCD, ArgoCD
2. Authenticate Pods to Google Cloud resources through Workload Identity, allowing Pods to act as an IAM service account. This allows you to give fine-grained identity and authorization to Pods when they need access to Google Cloud APIs.

---

Snippet from

- https://betterprogramming.pub/k8s-tips-using-a-serviceaccount-801c433d0023

A lot of applications that run in the cluster (read: running in Pods), need to communicate with the API server. Among them are the processes running within the Control Plane (scheduler, controller manager, proxy, etc.), as well as all the applications that need to perform some form of administration for the cluster.

For example, some applications might need to know

1 The status of the cluster’s nodes.

2 The namespaces available.

3 The Pods running in the cluster, or in a specific namespace.

4 etc.

---

Anything that needs to persist into ETCD needs to be authenticated and authorized

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/controlling-access/

---

Furthermore, there is another use-case what comes into my mind which is not directly internal cluster relevant.
If you have a central secret management tool like Hashicorp Vault and you use Kube-auth to this Vault then you need a serviceaccount token in order to authenticate to the Vault as well.

Answer (score 0):

In [this section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/service-accounts/#use-cases) of the kube doc you can find some uses cases.

What it helps me the more to understand the need of service account is for exemple:

- I configured a persistent volume as volume in my pod, how the pod will be able to get these infos?
- I configured a configmap as volume in my pod, how the pod will be able to retrieve these infos?

In other words, if you make reference to any kube resources in your pod definition, think about how the pod will get the info.